# How to remove data from object tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have object like this:

```
Subject {
 id:1
 packages: [
   {id:1, isChecked:true, ...},
   {id:2, isChecked:false, ...},
   {id:3, isChecked:true, themes:[

       {id:1, isChecked:true},
       {id:1, isChecked:false},
   ]
 ]
 ...
}
```

How can i remove all not checked items from this object please? I have to send this updated object to another component in react app.

The real tree looks like this:

```
Subject
|-packages 
  |-themes  (check if checked)
    |-themeParts (check if checked)
      |-exercises (check if checked)
```

If any of child is  checked it should be added to new component. So if I have Two packages and only one exercise is checked it is also checked themmeparts of this exercise, also theme of theme part and theme. Packages don't have isChecked attribute but i have to add this level to new object too if any of its child is checked.

Other example... if second package has no theme,part or exercise checked i have to remove from package level down alll...

So when i finish i need to have only Subject{} object with checked items + package of that checked items...

I hope i described it good XD....

anyway i tried something like this:

```
returnSelectedItems(){
        console.log(this.state.data);
        let newData = cloneDeep(this.state.data);
        newData.packages = [];

        this.state.data.packages.forEach((pckg) => {
            const newPackage = {

            };
            pckg.themes.forEach((theme, key) => {
                if(theme.isChecked){

                }
            });
        });

        console.log(newData);
        console.log(newData.packages);
        console.log(newData.packages[0].themes);
        console.log(newData.packages[0].themes[0].themeParts);
    }
```

But this is useless i think and i really don't know how to od it properly and ezy as it can be.. Thx for help

Comment: Are you based on ```themes``` id to delete object item?

Comment: Does the main object `{id:1
 packages: [..] }` have the `isChecked` key as well? It would help if it did

Comment: No it doesn't anyway i put here solution alredy.

Comment: but thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generic function like this. This takes an array as input and reduces it recursively for any nested array property. Destructure the object and get the array property to a `rest` object. If the `rest` object has any keys, recursively call the function to filter for the `isChecked` property.

This will work for any name of the array property for any number of nesting

```
function getChecked(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, { id, isChecked, ...rest }) => {
    if (isChecked) {
      const o = { id, isChecked };
      const [key] = Object.keys(rest);

      if (key)
        o[key] = getChecked(rest[key]);

      acc.push(o)
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
}

const output = {
  id: input.id,
  packages: getChecked(input.packages)
};
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
function getChecked(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, { id, isChecked, ...rest }) => {
    if (isChecked) {
      const o = { id, isChecked };
      const [key] = Object.keys(rest);
      
      if (key)
        o[key] = getChecked(rest[key]);
        
      acc.push(o)
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
}

const input = {
  id: 1,
  packages: [
    { id: 1, isChecked: true },
    { id: 2, isChecked: false },
    { id: 3, isChecked: true, themes: [
        {
          id: 4, isChecked: true, themeParts: [
            { id: 5, isChecked: true, exercises: [
                { id: 7, isChecked: true },
                { id: 8, isChecked: false }
              ]
            },
            { id: 6, isChecked: true }
          ]
        },
        { id: 9, isChecked: false }
      ]
    },
    { id: 10, isChecked: true },
  ]
};

const output = {
  id: input.id,
  packages: getChecked(input.packages)
};

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want. That's parent cannot be removed if children(themes) need to be kept

```
var subjects = {
  id: 1,
  packages: [{
      id: 1,
      isChecked: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      isChecked: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      isChecked: true,
      themes: [{
          id: 1,
          isChecked: true
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          isChecked: false
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function purge(item) {
   purgeItems(item.themes ||[]);
   return !item.isChecked && (item.themes ||[]).length === 0;
}

function purgeItems(themes) {
  var toremove = [];
  themes.forEach(function(p, i) {
    if (purge(p)) {
      toremove.push(i)
    }
  });
  while (toremove.length > 0) {
    themes.splice(toremove.pop(), 1);
  }
}

purgeItems(subjects.packages);
console.log(JSON.stringify(subjects));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i needed. using this principe: let {packages: packages, ...newData} = tempData;

```
 returnSelectedItems(){
        let tempData = cloneDeep(this.state.data);
        let {packages: packages, ...newData} = tempData;
        this.state.data.packages.forEach(pckg => {
            const {themes,...newPckg} = pckg;
            newPckg.themes = [];

            pckg.themes.forEach(theme =>{
               if(!theme.isChecked){
                  return;
               }
                const {themeParts, ...newTheme} = theme;
                newTheme.themeParts =[];
                newPckg.themes.push(newTheme);

                theme.themeParts.forEach(part =>{
                    if(!part.isChecked){
                        return;
                    }

                    const {knowledges, ...newPart} = part;
                    newPart.knowledges = [];
                    newTheme.themeParts.push(newPart);

                    part.knowledges.forEach(knowledge =>{
                        if(!knowledge.isChecked){
                            return;
                        }
                        newPart.knowledges.push(knowledge);
                    });
                });


            });

            if(newPckg.themes.length > 0){
                newData.packages = newPckg;
            }
        });

        return newData;
    }
```